# How do I add an icon to launchpad in os x mountain lion that will launch a java .jar?

Tags: java, macos, shortcut

Let's say I want an icon in Launchpad that when clicked on executes:

```
java -jar /Users/me/Program.jar argument1 argument2
```

I'm running OS X Mountain Lion.  This is a little Java program I wrote for my own personal use, nothing I'm trying to distribute.  Basically, I'm asking:  How do I make the equivalent of a Windows shortcut?

Comment: I believe you need to create a "app" bundle in order to get this to work. There's a verity of documents on the web, but [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) might be starting point...ohh and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/java/conceptual/java14development/03-javadeployment/javadeployment.html) one

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer both those links helped and I got it working.  The first one was the most useful.  I now have my .jar converted to a .app but I want to "Keep in Dock" but it is a program that I run once a day, and it runs for less than 10 seconds.  Is there anyway to set "Keep in Dock" on an .app that does run long enough for me to right click->Options->Keep in Dock?

Answer (score -1):

How about writing a shell script to execute the command and create a desktop shortcut like [this](http://lifehacker.com/5809871/how-to-make-a-desktop-shortcut-in-mac-os-x), or [this](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=70973)?

p.s. I'm not a mac user btw.  lol